# Populating a HoH, whose outer hash keys are in one array, and inner hash values are in another

Tags: perl, data-structures

**Explanation**

One array holds a set of keys. The values to these keys are inner hashes. The keys of these inner hashes, in this case are numbers (like array indices). Another array holds the values of the inner hash.

**Question:**

How can you populate the outer hash keys with the correct corresponding values (ie. correct inner hash)?

**Contraints**

I'd prefer a solution utilizing slices, map or grep. Eliminating cascading for loops

I realize it should be an HoA. But this is only for me to learn, it has no functional value...

**Working Code**:

This code works as I want but I would like to use more advanced techniques:

```
#! usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %register=();

my @classNames = ('Science_class', 'Math_class');
my @Science_class_student_names = ('George', 'Lisa', 'Mathias'); #prob from file
my @Math_class_student_names = ('Martin', 'Anna', 'Peter', 'George'); #prob from file

foreach my $className (@classNames) {
    my $array_name = $className.'_'.'student_names';
    if ($array_name =~ /Science/) {
        foreach (0..$#Science_class_student_names ) {
            $register{$className}{$_ + 1} = $Science_class_student_names[$_];
        }
    }
    elsif ($array_name =~ /Math/) {
        foreach (0..$#Math_class_student_names ) {
            $register{$className}{$_ + 1} = $Math_class_student_names[$_];
        }
    }
}

print Dumper(\%register);
```

---

**Ideas**

A hash slice works for direct key-value pairs, but the intermediate keys are throwing me off. Trying something like: `@register{@classNames} = map{$count => $student}`

One idea I had, before the if statements was if there was a way to use a string in the name of an array: `$#($array_name)student_names` but that doesn't work.

Another would be to separately create an array of all the inner hash keys, use a slice and then put that hash into the outer hash.

The only other idea I had was using an AoA to hold all the 'inner hash value' arrays. (ie. `my @studentNames = (\@Science_class_student_names, \@Math_class_student_names);` but haven't gotten anywhere with that yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier to work on it a layer at a time. For the inner layer, it seems you want

```
1 => George,
2 => Lisa,
...
```

So start by figuring out how to do that.

```
map { $_+1 => $Science_class_student_names[$_] }
   0..$#Science_class_student_names
```

So you end up with

```
$register{'Science_class'} = {
   map { $_+1 => $Science_class_student_names[$_] }
      0..$#Science_class_student_names
   }
};

$register{'Math_class'} = {
   map { $_+1 => $Math_class_student_names[$_] }
      0..$#Math_class_student_names
   }
};
```

If you generalise the inner layer, you get

```
for (
   [ 'Science_class' => \@Science_class_student_names ],
   [ 'Math_class'    => \@Math_class_student_names ],
) {
   my ($class_name, $student_names) = @$_;
   $register{$class_name} = {
      map { $_+1 => $student_names->[$_] }
         0..$#$student_names
   };
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for giving the thought process. My one question is: Can the outer layer be generalized, instead of having to type: `'Science_class' => \@Science_class_student_names` for each 'class'(which I had to do using the if-else)? It doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Whew! Figured it out (as long as they are inputted in the same order) :`my %classhash;` 
`@classhash{@classNames} = @studentNames;`Note:(`@studentNames` is AoA as shown in Ideas section of question). Then replace your for loop with:
`for (keys %classhash) {` and replace the declarations:
   `my $class_name = $_;
   my $student_names = $classhash{$_};`